# Probability: Normal Distribution

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

> 1. Each item produced by a certain manufacturer is, independently, of acceptable quality with probability $0.95$. Approximate the
>      probability (by a normal distribution) that at most $10$ of the next
>      $150$ items produced are unacceptable.
> 2. Hits to a high-volume Web site are assumed to follow a Poisson distribution with a mean of $10,000$ per day.
>
> $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(a)}$ Approximate (by a normal
>   distribution) the expected number of days in a year ($365$ $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$years) that
>   exceed $10,200$ hits.
>
> $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(b)}$ Approximate (by a normal
>   distribution) the probability that over a year ($365$ days) $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$more than
>   $15$ days each have more than $10,200$ hits.

For question 1, is the answer $0.8695$?

For question 2(a), is that I have to use P(X<= 10199.5) to find the probability and multiply the probability by $365$ ?

For question 2(b), would anyone mind telling me how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Question 1)

Model the number of unacceptable items as normal, p=.05.

$\hat\mu = .05(150) = 7.5\space,\hat\sigma = \sqrt{150(.05)(.95)} = 2.67$

Normal Approximation: F = No. of Unacceptable Items, $F \sim N(7.5,2.67)$

$P(F\leq 10) = \Phi(\frac{10-7.5+.5}{0.84}) = 0.87$ Using the continuity correction.

So, your first answer is correct.

Question 2)

a) Your approach is generally correct. You want to calcluate $P(X\geq 10,201)$ using the normal approximation ($\hat \mu = \hat \sigma^2 = 10,000 $and multiply by 365.

b) HINT: You'll need to first approximate $P(X\geq 10,201)$ as before then use the *Binomial* distribution to get the probability for the number of days.

Comment: So, for question 2(b), is the answer 0.9906 ?

Comment: you mean I should use the negative binomial distribution?

Comment: Part a is asking for an expected value not a probability. also yours seems very high. for B....No, binomial dist should be used

Comment: Well, I mean for 2(a), the answer is 8.103 days, so is the answer 9 days?

Comment: Also, for 2(b), is the answer 0.01134 ?

Comment: Your first answer is correct - 8.1 or approx 8 days. The associated probability is 0.022 for any given day. Now, out of 365 days we want to know the probability of getting over 15 such days. Using the cumulative binomial distribution, we calculate this as $1-CumulativeBin(15,365,.022) = 0.0077$. Using the normal approximation to the binomial, we get $1-\Phi(\frac{15-8.1}{\sqrt{365(.022)(1-.022)}}) = .0063$. I'm not sure how you got .01134.